# window azure mobile service for android fetching multiple records based on different values

Tags: android, azure-storage, azure-table-storage, azure-mobile-services

I am using window azure mobile service for creating database in my android application.
I have given third party library to access all the details within the table.However these library do not have same method like sql language for database and hence i have to make very complex queries for that.
i am stuck with the issue in which i have to fetch multiple records based on different values for selected columns like there is an column named "id" and i have to fetch records for id 1 ,3,7 and 10 .
Do any one have experience with this third party library.
Please guide me if anyone have some familiar experience.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which third party library are you talking about? Without this information it's really hard for us to guess how to access the table using this library.

Comment: i am using mobile-service 0.2.0 library (a library provided by microsoft azure portal) for communication between azure database and my android application and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: @kaushaltrivedi ... hey can you answer my question ...plzzzzz http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31364134/java-how-to-retrieve-and-use-a-single-value-from-azure-mobile-services-in-andr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Android SDK for Azure Mobile Services has a query language in which you can make sql-like queries. For your specific example, here's how you'd do it.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    try {
        mClient = new MobileServiceClient(
                  "https://YOUR_AZURE_MOBILE_SERVICE.azure-mobile.net/",
                  "YOUR_APPLICATION_KEY",
                  this
            );
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    final TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            MobileServiceTable<Person> table = mClient.getTable("Test", Person.class);
            table.where(
                field("id").eq(1)
                .or(field("id").eq(3))
                .or(field("id").eq(7))
                .execute(new TableQueryCallback<Person>() {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted(List<Person> result, int count,
                        Exception exception, ServiceFilterResponse response) {

                    if (exception != null) {
                        tv.setText(exception.toString());
                    } else {
                        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                        for (Person p : result) {
                            sb.append("P[name=");
                            sb.append(p.name);
                            sb.append(",age=");
                            sb.append(p.age);
                            sb.append("],");
                        }

                        tv.setText(sb.toString());
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    });
}
```

AFAIK the documentation is still being published, but you can look at some examples at https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-mobile-services/blob/master/sdk/android/test/sdk.testapp.tests/src/com/microsoft/windowsazure/mobileservices/sdk/testapp/test/MobileServiceQueryTests.java.

Comment: thank you so much buddy it works really well and link you have provided has potential information i was searching .thnx again.

Comment: @carlosfigueira ... hey can you answer my question ...plzzzzz http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31364134/java-how-to-retrieve-and-use-a-single-value-from-azure-mobile-services-in-andr

Answer (score 0):

there are several ways to make the communication between the Android and the WIndows Azure.  you can do this whether using the WCF (windows communication foundation) and pass the URL of the Service to your android, or you can start using the Windows Azure Mobile Service  where you can start working whether on the Mobile Service (Dynamic Data Schema) or to link it to your storage account on Windows Azure using Node JS.

Here is the link to start with the WCF:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734712.aspx

Here is the link to start with the Windows Azure Mobile Service:  http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/

here is the link to start with the Node JS http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/#