# Java - How to Retrieve and use a single value from azure mobile services in Android

Tags: java, android, azure, azure-mobile-services

I am new to azure but i know certain things like how to retrieve and store data to azure , i followed azure official documentation for this purpose.

Link is Here - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/mobile-services-android-get-started-data/

But the problem is, this tutorial is only showing How to retrieve and use Data from azure using Adapters and Lists . **I want to know , How can i retrieve a single value from azure mobile services and how to use it in android**.

Plzz provide me both backend code (if there is any) and java code for this . THANKS in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it solved. No need to create a custom API.

Just follow the basics , Here is the code :-

```
final String[] design = new String[1];

private MobileServiceTable<User> mUser;

mUser = mClient.getTable(User.class);

            new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    try {
                        final MobileServiceList<User> result =
                                mUser.where().field("name").eq(x).execute().get();
                        for (User item : result) {
                           // Log.i(TAG, "Read object with ID " + item.id);
                            desig[0] = item.getDesignation(); //getDesignation() is a function in User class ie- they are getters and setters
                            Log.v("FINALLY DESIGNATION IS", desig[0]);

                        }

                    } catch (Exception exception) {
                       exception.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
                    designation.setText(desig[0]);
                }
            }.execute();
```

**DON'T** forget to create a class `User` for `serialization` and all. Also you should define the array .

**FEEL FREE to write** if you got it not working.

**EDIT :-**

`design[0]` is an array with size 1.

`eq(x)` is equal to `x` where , `x` variable contains username for which i want designation from database (azure).

Comment: hey, can i just now what is desig[0] and .eq(x)? what should they be defined as?

Comment: design[0] is an array ... you should define it with size 1. see the edited part.' final String[] design = new String[1];'

Comment: eq(x) is equal to x where x variable contains username for which i want designation from database.

Comment: @kumarkundan I am going to add user in Table User. But i am not able to add it. I got error like this. can you please help me in that.

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceException: {"message":"The operation failed with the following error: 'A null store-generated value was returned for a non-nullable member 'CreatedAt' of type 'CrazyLabApp.Models.User'.'."}

Comment: @iDroidExplorer hey...it's a different question or issue ...start a new question....and give me the link to your question .... i will try to answer

Comment: @kumarkundan please check this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31557886/azuremobileservice-insert-data-in-to-table-gives-exception

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a custom API. See this link: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-how-to-use-server-scripts/#custom-api

Code looks like this:

```
exports.post = function(request, response) {
    response.send(200, "{ message: 'Hello, world!' }");
}
```

It's then reachable at `https://todolist.azure-mobile.net/api/APIFILENAME`.

If you want to access a table you can do something like:

```
exports.post = function(request, response) {
    var userTable = tables.getTable('users');

    permissionsTable
        .where({ userId: user.userId})
        .read({ success: sendUser });
} 

function sendUser(results){
  if(results.length <= 0) {
    res.send(200, {});
  } else {
    res.send(200, {result: results[0]});
  }
}
```

You can then follow the instructions for using the API on your Android client here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-android-call-custom-api/

How your app is written will change how this code works/looks, but it looks something like:

```
ListenableFuture<MarkAllResult> result = mClient.invokeApi( "UsersAPI", MarkAllResult.class );
```

That invokes the API. You need to write the class and Future to handle the results. The above page explains this in great detail.

Comment: okk ........Let i want to access designation of a user "sumit" ( "sumit" should come from my android application as a parameter or whatsoever ) . Now tell me how can i do that ...more specifically how to pass parameter to api or there is a way to filter it in java ... i already did a lot of google to find this answer .... any help or suggestion will be good . By the way thanks for your rply.

Comment: one more thing....it's showing tables,permissiontable,res as could not find symbol.

Comment: If you're just looking to get back a single record, you should use the tables API and then filter from there. Less work on you. The Azure Documentation site has lots of guidance on this. What you're asking is a different question, so you'd be better off starting a new SO post.

Comment: ok .. but tell me why i am getting " could not find symbol" error. see my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

The most optimal solution would be to create an api on your server which accepts an ID to return an single object/tablerow.

In your android app, you only have to call:

```
MobileServiceTable<YourClass> mYourTable;

mClient = new MobileServiceClient(
                        "https://yoursite.azurewebsites.net/",
                        mContext);
mYourTable = mClient.getTable(YourClass.class);
YourClass request = mYourTable.lookUp(someId).get(); 
// request -> https://yoursite.azurewebsites.net/tables/yourclass/someId
```

`YourClass` should have the same properties as the object on the server.