# How to retrieve from Azure mobile services using android studio

Tags: java, android, azure

I am new to Android and Windows Azure. I have successfully inserted data from Android application but how do I retrieve single data and post that data on a `TextView`?

The read function after the gettable class is also not working. What is the exact function use for it? I have followed these [instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31364134/java-how-to-retrieve-and-use-a-single-value-from-azure-mobile-services-in-andr) but they did not work for me, also I do not understand the documentation.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. When you ask a question, please supply the relevant parts of the code, to show what you have tried. Be specific about what is working and what is not. If you get error messages or unexpected responses from your code, supply those as well. 

Also, please use line breaks when you write and see the formatting guide on how to format code. (see: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 0):

Currently, I just can provide some tutorials about how to use query data from azure database. I recommend you can refer to this official document about how to use Azure Client Library using Java: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-android-how-to-use-client-library . You can focus on two part: “how to query data from a mobile service” and “how to bind data to the UI”.

At the same time, you can view this video from Channel 9: https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Azure-Mobile-Services/Android-Getting-Started-With-Data-Connecting-your-app-to-Windows-Azure-Mobile-Services.

The sample code project of this tutorial, please go to the GitHub link https://github.com/Azure/mobile-services-samples/tree/master/GettingStartedWithData .

For the ‘getTable(Class )’ function is not working, please double check whether the class name is same as table name. If they are same, you can use it like below:

```
MobileServiceTable<ToDoItem> mToDoTable = mClient.getTable(ToDoItem.class);
```

If not, you can write you code like this:

```
MobileServiceTable<ToDoItem> mToDoTable = mClient.getTable("ToDoItemBackup", ToDoItem.class);
```

For further better support, please share more detail about your code snippet .